# failed to send join request to master

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using elasticsearch version `1.3.0`. After restarting data node its unable to detect master node. I am getting error `failed to send join request to master`

In Error log :-

```
[[app101][dGRBqTFTQfae76IFCjsMmQ][app101][inet[/127.0.0.2:9300]]{master=true, river=_none_}], 
reason [org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: 
[app101][inet[/127.0.0.2:9300]][discovery/zen/join];
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException:
[app102][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]][discovery/zen/join/validate];
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: 
No custom index metadata factory registered for type [rivers]]
```

**Edit:**
after reinstalling jdbc river fix the problem. But still I am looking the way if remove jdbc river and restart the ES cluster. Then it should detect master node.

Comment: Having this issue now - to clarify, you removed jdbc river from the data node or the master node? Did you have to restart the master node to clear the issue?

Comment: Yes we restart that node after removing head plugin as it will not detect master node automatically. If your master node is different then no need to restart it.