# Adding node to ES with different version on both machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster on two node with version 1.3.1

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "name": "Blue Streak",
  "version": {
    "number": "1.3.1",
    "build_hash": "2de6dc5268c32fb49b205233c138d93aaf772015",
    "build_timestamp": "2014-07-28T14:45:15Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "4.9"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now i need to add a node to this cluster but the version of elasticsearch on new node is 1.5.2

```
{
  "status": 503,
  "name": "Adrian Toomes",
  "cluster_name": "tg-elasticsearch",
  "version": {
    "number": "1.5.2",
    "build_hash": "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
    "build_timestamp": "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Can this be possible? Since when i am trying to connect it is giving following error:

```
[2015-08-13 14:41:16,840][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [10.33.57.169] Message not fully read (request) for [21602710] and action [discovery/zen/join/validate], resetting
[2015-08-13 14:41:16,859][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [10.33.57.169] failed to send join request to master [[Blue Streak][iNUjaFvqTu6nbzjgOr14rQ][tg-db3][inet[/10.65.40.65:9300]]], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Blue Streak][inet[/10.65.40.65:9300]][discovery/zen/join]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[10.33.57.169][inet[/10.33.57.169:9300]][discovery/zen/join/validate]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No custom index metadata factory registered for type [rivers]]; ]
```

Comment: Do you have the elasticsearch-river plugin? It looks a lot like [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030778/failed-to-send-join-request-to-master)

Comment: I saw it is  Deprecated in 1.5.2